# CSS3 animation of background-color not working in Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations

I have been working with changing the background colour of an element using css3 animations. However it does not work in Chrome. I have attached a jsFiddle example of the code I am using. It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome and despite my best efforts I have been unable to work out what the problem is.

In chrome is seems to ignore the reference to background-color only. If I move the item or apply any other effect to the element it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/qWKEs/6/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in chrome. Should be fixed in version 18 as per http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101245

Comment: I see. Thank you. I saw that, but I assumed that that applied to all CSS animations. And not just transitions/animations involving colour changes.

Comment: Yea, that bit me on a project too. Will be nice when they get this one fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue using the `background` property in Chrome with CSS3.

However the version of Chrome is 21.0.1180.83 (up to date as of 8/24/12) so the problem still exists.

I resolved it by specifying `background-color` instead and that works fine.

[image]

Interestingly enough the W3C says it's only supported in version 1.